# Why build relationships into databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm just wondering why you would go to the trouble of specifying relationships between tables.

Is it just for referential integrity?

Comment: You don't think it's worth doing just to ensure the integrity of your data? I guess it also serves as documentation.

Comment: That's not what I meant. Just wanted to know if serves any other purpose e.g speed of queries

Comment: What comes to performance foreign keys will make making changes to the database (insert/update/delete) slightly slower because it has to check the constraints to make sure you're not trying to break them.

Comment: *just for referential integrity* - that's the ***backbone*** of why you're using databases! Ensuring that your data **is consistent and makes sense!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensuring integrity ON THE SERVER has several obvious advantages I can think of:
- it will always be faster than if done by the client (no roundtrips)
- it will protect against developer errors
- you can't always control which client connects to your data